# Adding a div tooltip inside a Raphael canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Is it possible to add a div element inside a canvas and its position is relative to the canvas?

I'm using panzoom plugin and the div is not panning with the canvas. (because I think it is not inside the canvas)

Comment: No, you can't have a div or hteml element inside an svg (unless as a foreignObject, but thats not that well supported really). You could possibly overlay a div absolutely or similar.

Comment: Is there a way that I could make my div pan with my canvas?

Comment: if you use absolute positioning and adjust that, I think it would be possible.

Comment: i'll try that. thank you :)